# What's the purpose of this link in this java doc?

Tags: java, concurrency, doc

I am wondering what's the purpose of the link **SkipLists** present in this javadoc [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html):

Once opened the link `ctrl +f` and type `SkipLists` then click on the link, I am curious to know on a scale from 0 to 10 how much the link relates to the argument.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a link to the Class upon which its built, the SkipList, but it obviously has succumbed to Link rot, and the link is now bad.

Comment: The link has been fixed in [Java 7 JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)

Comment: Oh I see.  Bill Pugh invented skip lists so the class is trying to give credit to the data type author.

Comment: Haha - some sort of easter egg? Bill Pugh is one of the guys who rewrote the Java Memory Model for Java 5 (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1011627/journal.pdf).